# How do I use a JMeter Variable declared in an extractor in a User Defined Variable config

Tags: jmeter

I have an http request that uses an extractor to set a JMeter variable (lets call it `test`) from the body. When I look at the debug controller I can see this works fine. Next I want to append something to the beginning of the variable so I add a user defined variable node and add a variable with the name `new` and I set the value to `${test}`. However when I look in the debug response I see `${test}` instead of the value.

I tried the same thing setting the value manually in 2 different UDV nodes and it works fine, so how do I append to a JMeter variable declared in an extractor?

Answer (score 1):

UDVs can't be used in dynamic way because they are process once at the start of the test.

Don't use UDV, use JSR223 Sampler (or PostProcessor) with `vars`;

```
 vars.put("new", "prefix"+ vars.get("test"))
```

Another option is to use [Set Variables Action](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction) plugin

Comment: So does this mean it just isn't really supported? This was the way I was leaning.

Comment: @JGleason UDV are process only at start, you can check also https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> The User Defined Variables element lets you define an **initial set of variables**, just as in the Test Plan.
>
> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - **are processed at the start**.

So the User Defined Variables element will be read only once and only when the Test Plan is started.

If you need to overwrite the current variable with a new value you can go for i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.put('foo'\, 'some_prefix_' + vars.get('foo')),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

`vars` is a shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance, it provides read-write access to all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the current thread scope. Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) to learn what else you can do with Groovy scripting in JMeter tests